# Verifying Salt states before committing

Tags: git, saltstack, yaml

I'm storing my salt sls files in a git repository, but I have the perennial problem that I can't verify my YAML represents a valid set of states that could be applied (I've also had difficulty validating my YAML -- that's much easier, though).  Ideally, I'd like some way to verify my states on my workstation before committing them.  Failing that, some way to check in a pre-receive hook so I can at least stop dodgy code from hitting the server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287346/yaml-validation

Comment: Thanks @ceejayoz, that's not a bad idea :).  Whipped a one-liner in Python to do the same job, and a pre-commit hook won't be hard.  I'll edit the question to emphasise the difficult bit...

Comment: Could you post your solution as your answer?

Comment: @davey, I only have an answer to the tangental question of validating YAML, not to the question of verifying Salt state files.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to try the test option with the salt command: http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/testing.html

```
salt '*' state.highstate test=True
```

This also works with the salt-call command. It will parse all configuration files, will run all checks and will then list all commands that it would have been executed.